# How can I move windows between desktops with the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10-preview

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>  move the viewport between virtual desktops.

How I can move *the active window* between virtual desktops using the keyboard, however?

Comment: I'm using build 10240, so I don't think we can really talk about Windows 10 previews... but I could be wrong

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've seen that question and, as any questions that asks if there are "any" keyboard shortcuts for virtual desktops, its answers are incomplete and fail to address my specific request.

Comment: @badp, if you feel it's not a dupe, then edit your question and make this clear, show this other question and explain why your question is different (just to make it super clear) :) Otherwise it could  get closed as a dupe if people don't read the comments (which are hard to spot in the review tools we have)